# Accessing the environment a function is defined in, from outside the function

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a closure in `R` that looks something like the following:

```
closure <- function(driver=system.file("java/driver.jar", package="fake"),
                    db_username=.getDb_username(), 
                    db_password=.getDb_password(), 
                    db_name=.getDb_name(),
                    tunnel="ssh command"){
  system(tunnel)
  drv <- JDBC("db.jdbc.Driver",
              driver,
              identifier.quote="`")
  db_con <- dbConnect(drv, db_name, db_username, db_password)

  runQuery <- function(sql_query, ...){
    sql_query <- processQuery(sql_query, ...)

    return(.dbRunQuery(db_con, sql_query, dbGetQuery))

  }
  return(runQuery)
}
```

Then I run the following code:

```
closure_return <- closure()
```

**Now, I want to access `db_con` from `closure_return`.  Is this possible?  If so how?**

Note that I don't want to change `closure` in any way.  If changing `closure` is the only way that's fine, but please try to provide an answer that does not involve changing `closure`.

Please let me know if you need any clarification or if I'm using the word "closure" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm silly.

Answer found here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures

More information can also be found at `?environment`.

I can simply run `environment(closure_return)` and access the vars there.

Comment: @Frank I get no return when typing that into the R console

Comment: @Frank yeah looks like the `environment` documentation would be good as well.  Adding it.

Comment: Okay, gonna delete my comments. "Cleaning up" and that